# How can I display the data from Mysql table in jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp

Please, HELP!
Many days I try to display the data from Mysql Data. I tried to display data by may different ways. But no succcess. I connected to Mysql DB. I can extract it like ArrayList using ${} but cannot extract in a needed tag.

This is jsp file:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@ page import="AdditionalLibraris.MysqlConnection" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> -- login --</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Login/login.css">
</head>
<body>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@ page import="AdditionalLibraris.MysqlConnection" %>
<% ArrayList<String> itStaff = MysqlConnection.itStaff(); %>
<%= itStaff%> <---- displays----------------------- 
<div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="logo">
           <h2>Logo</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="login_form">
            <div class="inputItem">
                <label for="op_name">Name</label>
                <select id="op_name">
                    <option>choose</option>
                    <c:forEach var="userName"  <----  not displays------------
                           items="${MysqlConnection.itStaff()}">
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Login/login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is MySQL Connector.

```
package AdditionalLibraris;

import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MysqlConnection {
     public static Connection connection( String dbName) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        Connection con = null;
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/"+dbName+"?useSSL=false";
        String userName = "admin";
        String password = "admin";
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, userName, password);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Exception e1 = e;
        }
        return con;
    }

    public static ArrayList itStaff(){
        Statement pstms;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        String sqlrequest = "select it_username from it_persons";
        try {
            Connection con = MysqlConnection.connection("inventory_it_assets");
            System.out.println(con);
            pstms = con.createStatement();
            resultSet = pstms.executeQuery(sqlrequest);

            while(resultSet.next()){
                String name = resultSet.getString("it_username");
                arr.add(name);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

[image: I can not see the list of users from DB. But you can see that in top I can see the arraylist of users.]

What I do wrong? Or I miss something....I just started to learn JavaEE and probably dont know something.

Thank you in advance.
Regards.

I tried to display the MySQL table in jsp.
I tried with for loop with foreach loop... still can not see the list

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your array is retrieving correctly your data, you can try something different to call it's values.

As you made here `<%= itStaff%>` check how i used `<%` and `%>` tags to open and close backend instructions.
<%

```
/**
 * Declaring variables
 */
ArrayList<String> itStaff = MysqlConnection.itStaff(); 

/**
 * Printing our combo.
 */
%>
<select id="" class="" required>
    <option value="">-- select a value --</option>
    <%
        for(int i = 0; i < itStaff.size(); i++){
    %>
            <option value="<%=isStaff.get(i)%>"><%=isStaff.get(i)%></option>
    <% 
        }
    %>
</select>
```

Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: I am sure. Because when i call list with <%= itStaff%> it shows me the list of it staff. When i try to display it with for loop, as you showed, it shows me the error that i can no place <% %> inside the for loop. It seams that i have to install some dependencies. And that is what i am trying to do now....

Comment: Let me see how you are using <%%> and <%=%> cause they have different purposes. 
Im not pretty sure that is dependency troubles, cause those tags are native from java scriptlets.